# can we find the area under a curve that is not a function?

Tags: calculus, parametric

I am doing parametric calculus now, and I went the process of finding the area under a parametric curve, and one of the conditions to find the is that the curve has to represent a function on that interval. My question is that cant we find the area under a curve that is not a function, but we can break it or cut it to into subintervals so that these subintervals do represent a function and find the areas of these subintervals and then sum them up?

Comment: How would you define the “area under the curve” that is not a function? What happens when part of the curve is above or below itself?

Comment: Yes! That can be done.

Comment: how can it be done?

Comment: You mean something like $x=A\cos t$ and $y=A\sin t$?

Comment: no, since the upper part will cancel the lower part

Comment: some interval that does not satisfy the vertical line test

Comment: So if I move the center of the center up, is that OK?

Comment: Give a concrete example

Comment: (x-2)^2  +  (y-5)^2    =  9  is an example

Comment: And you want the area of the disk?